# How to efficiently handle a collection of millions of tuples in java?

Tags: java, vector, collections, arraylist

I'm working on a java program which actually retrieve tuples from a postgresql database and do some works with them. I represent each tuple as a `Vector` of `String` and the complete set of tuple (resultSet) as a vector of tuple.

```
Vector<String>         tuple;
Vector<Vector<String>> resultSet;
```

In my application, I need to handle several Millions of tuples. Here is a simple benchmark which simulate my program by simply reading X tuples in a resultSet and then printing the the resultSet Size, the first and the last tuple.

The benchmark consider using vector and arrayList to represent tuples

```
List<String>       tuple;
List<List<String>> resultSet;
```

The benchmark program code

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VectorVSarrayList {

  public static void loadDataInVector(Integer size){

    Vector<Vector<String>> r     = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    Vector<String>         tuple = new Vector<String>();

    startTimer();  

    for(Integer i = 0; i < size; i++){

      tuple = new Vector<String>();

      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
        tuple.add(i.toString() + " tuple "+j);

      r.add(tuple);

    }

    endTimer("vector size " + r.size() + " first element : " + r.get(0).get(0) + ", and     last element : " + r.get(r.size()-1).get(0)); 

    r.clear();

  }

  public static void loadDataInArrayList(Integer size){

    List<List<String>> r     = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String>       tuple = new ArrayList<String>();


    startTimer();    

    for(Integer i = 0; i < size; i++){

      tuple = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
        tuple.add(i.toString() + " tuple "+j);

     r.add(tuple);
    }

    endTimer("array  size " + r.size() + " first element : " + r.get(0).get(0) + ", and  last element : " + r.get(r.size()-1).get(0)); 

    r.clear();       
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){

    Integer size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    loadDataInArrayList(size);
    loadDataInVector(size);

    loadDataInArrayList(size);
    loadDataInVector(size);
  }

  private static long startTime = 0;
  private static long endTime   = 0;

  public static void startTimer(){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public static void endTimer(String log){
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(log + ", " + (endTime - startTime) + ", ms");
 }


}
```

I've run the benchmark to handle 1 and 10 millions of tuple with java heap size extension to 2G, here are the results

```
> time java -Xmx2g VectorVSarrayList 1000000
array  size 1000000 first element : 0 tuple 0, and last element : 999999 tuple 0, 1642, ms
vector size 1000000 first element : 0 tuple 0, and last element : 999999 tuple 0, 1075, ms
array  size 1000000 first element : 0 tuple 0, and last element : 999999 tuple 0, 1625, ms
vector size 1000000 first element : 0 tuple 0, and last element : 999999 tuple 0, 308, ms

real    0m4.829s
user    0m14.849s
sys     0m0.500s


> time java -Xmx2g VectorVSarrayList 10000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at VectorVSarrayList.loadDataInArrayList(VectorVSarrayList.java:72)
    at VectorVSarrayList.main(VectorVSarrayList.java:28)

real    6m12.708s
user    22m57.662s
sys     0m6.200s
```

These results show that even for only 10 millions tuples i will spend at least 6 minutes (versus 4 second for 1 millions) and eventually run through OutOfMemory

```
OS         : Ubuntu 12.04
RAM        : 6 GB
processor  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
```

Is there a good way (better collection type or better pratice) to do this type of work ?

Comment: To start, don't use `Vector`; it's been essentially deprecated since Java 1.2. Always prefer `List` unless working with ancient APIs that require `Vector`.

Comment: More generally speaking, the answer is *Don't Do That*. Grab the `ResultSet` object and iterate directly over that instead of trying to slurp the entire database into RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what "some work" means, you can optimize this problem that I understand as **grouping** the results from the database.

Obviously you could go for more efficient datastructures, that will not overflood your heap. But these will need maintenance every time the data changes (relevant). In the above case, create the ArrayList with an initial size of 3 or better use a LinkedList.

Another approach is to let the database already prepare the data such that this preparation is supporting your operations. like

- sort data ordered by your group key (in the database)
- iterator though the data, and fill A vector as long as the group key is the same
- when the group key changes do some work on the grouped sequence (like store or print out the first, the last and the size or whatever) and store only the relevant facts for that sequence.
- when the data is done, work on the per-sequence results, like aggregate them

This approach is known as MapReduce, here the Mapping is done (virtually) in the database and the reduction is done in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Make a Tuple class with variables for every String (or an ArrayList strings)
2. Implement and override a hashCode() method (e.g. by combining the return values of every hashCode of every String in the tuple)
3. Create a HashMap[10][10] hashMapArray = ...  and initialize HashMaps in every Subarray with two nested for loops.
4. Put every Tuple in the hashMapArray with:

   ```
   int hash = Math.abs(Tuple.hashCode());
   HashMap<Integer, Tuple> switchMap = hashMapArray [hash / 10][hash % 10];
   switchMap.put(Tuple.hashCode(), Tuple);
   ```

Using this approach (or a variation of it) will probably speed up your program quite a bit. I had to implement a fast way of sorting and getting hundreds of millions elements as well and with this the duration dropped from around 12 mins to some seconds. And please don't use Vector in the future, it is deprecated as hell :)

Hope this helps.